# how to fix length of value of <li>

Tags: html, css

I have a `balise <li>` that have a `backgroup` but the value of the `li` sometimes is too long .

so I want when the value is too long to show just the begin of the value then some point like that :

> 112312531821321 =======> 112312531..

Is there an option in `CSS` or `HTML` to do this ?

this is my code :

```
 <ul > 
  <ui:repeat value="#{op.orderedOf}" var="vari" > 
    <li class="item"  ><h:outputText value="#{vari}" /></li>
     </ui:repeat>                     
      </ul>
```

Comment: See this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802175/truncating-long-strings-with-css-feasible-yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ul li {

```
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**When can you use it!**

```
http://caniuse.com/#search=ellipsis
```

**SOLUTION FOR OPERA**

```
text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `ellipsis`

Here is the similar [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14641253/1033200) which I answered long ago